# Searching all Business components by functions they use, in UFT

Tags: search, ui-automation, hp-uft, business-process-management, alm

Is there an easy way to see all the Business components that are using a specific function in UFT or ALM?

There is a function which was scripted in my library and now i want to delete that function from my library.

If i delete the function from my script without removing it from all the business components that use it, my test could fail.

Answer (score 0):

I'd add some code to the function like so:

```
Dim oUft : Set oUft = CreateObject("QuickTest.Application")
Reporter.ReportEvent micWarning, _
                     "<YourFunctionName>", _
                     oUft.Test.Name & " uses function <YourFunctionName>"
```

That means that every time this function is called, it will output the test name to the test results.  Run with this for a week, or however long your test cycle is to make sure you have executed a full suite of tests, then scan the reports to identify all the tests using it.

All of my UFT scripts write their own text log files as I don't use the Test Results option - if you do similarly, then you could simply grep the log files for the message.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So i am guessing there isn't a feature available in QTP/UFT which allows me to do that. the only way to do it is by scripting some code.

Comment: That's correct. UFT provides no method by which you can track the use of components created other than that which you create yourself

Comment: Damn it. Exactly the reason i prefer an IDE like Visual Studio or Eclipse to do coding. The developer can stretch his arms around a bit.